# Page attribute value showing null in oracle webcenter sites 11g R1

Tags: webcenter-sites

Hi I am working in oracle webcenter Sites 11g. 
I have added a new page attribute name **pagetitle** and added that in `PageDefinition` and add a new template with JSP logic and added the code:

```
<%=ics.GetVar("pagetitle")%>
```

but when viewing the page after creating a new page , the value of `pagetitle` is showing `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the page asset first after read the required attributes.

Below is the sample code for display the 'pagetitle'

```
<assetset:setasset name="Page" type='<%=ics.GetVar("c")%>' id='<%=ics.GetVar("cid")%>' />
<assetset:getattributevalues name="Page" typename='PageAttribute' attribute='pagetitle' listvarname="pagetitlelist" />
<ics:listget fieldname="value" listname="pagetitlelist" output="title"/>
<%=ics.GetVar("title")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line in your JSP you can obtain all attibutes:

```
<ics:argument name="attributes" value="attribute1,attribute2,...,attributen" />
```

if want to use any attribute, do that.

For example: `${asset.attribute1}`